# Signals not received using QServiceManager

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with the QServiceManager.

```
QServiceManager manager;
CFoo bar;
QList<QServiceInterfaceDescriptor> ServiceList = manager.findInterfaces(SERVICE_NAME);

for(int i = 0; i < ServiceList.length(); i++)
{
   bool accessGranted = false;
   QServiceInterfaceDescriptor descriptor = ServiceList[i];
   if (descriptor.interfaceName() == INTERFACE)
   {
        bar = manager.loadLocalTypedInterface<IFoo>(descriptor, accessGranted);
        if (NULL == bar && false == accessGranted)
        {
            connect(bar,            SIGNAL(signal()),
                    this,                     SLOT(slot()));
        }
   } 
}
```

I can do function calls specified in the interface IFoo on bar, like:

```
bar.function()
```

and I see that the remote object foo is receiving the function call, but when I send the signal remotely:

```
 class IFoo : public QObject
 {
      Q_OBJECT          
 public:
     virtual void function() = 0:

 signals:
     void signal();
 };

 class CFoo : public IFoo`
 {
    Q_OBJECT      

    void function()
    {
        emit signal();
    }
};
```

it is not received. The function slot() is never called. I checked that the connect function gets called and returns TRUE. Can anybody pinpoint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: CFoo is not a `QObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Cant use signals and slots if your class isnt qobject

```
 #include<QObject>

 class CFoo : public QObject, public IFoo
 {
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:

         void signal();   

    public:

    void function()
    {
        emit signal();
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that IFoo inherrits from QObject. Sot that is not the problem.

Comment: @Frank: you also need to add macro `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: @Amartel I do that. See the implementation of IFoo

Comment: @Frank but CFoo should also inherit from QObject and have `Q_OBJECT` macro

Comment: im just going to assume you have defined `signal` in CFoo?

Comment: see updated answer, you also have `void CFoo::function()` in the header which im pretty sure is a compiler error

Comment: I added it, but still the same problem

Comment: did u inherit from QObject too, before inheriting from IFoo like my example,because your update doesnt show that